# OpenGL context conflict between Qt and a third party game engine - how to resolve?

Tags: qt, opengl, rendering, directx

I am trying to use an external to Qt OpenGL context using a window handle that comes from Qt. The setup is:

- A `QMainWindow` - contains various widgets including a `QWebEngineView` to make some web content available (in my case it's **Leaflet** for render and interact with OpenStreetMaps tiles)
- Panda3D engine - rendered on top of my Qt application using a window handle of the central `QWidget`.

The setup works...when Panda3D is set to DirectX9 (aka `pandadx9`). When I switch the pipeline to OpenGL (aka `pandagl`) I get a black screen (Panda3D's window) and a very glitch OpenGL content (Qt). The reason is simple yet beyond my ability to fix it - `QWebEngineView` uses OpenGL. Somehow there is a conflict on a OpenGL context level between the engine and Qt. I am looking for a way to resolve this without removing the direct interaction with Panda3D's window (in my case using `ShowBase`) since the engine already offers a lot in terms of features for handling mouse events that I would otherwise be forced to reimplement in Qt and pass down to the engine. In addition I am not sure if I can make Panda3D render its scene as an FBO and how to load it in a - let's say - `QOpenGLWidget`. Activating shared OpenGL context before initializing `QApplication` allows multiple OpenGL widgets to render OpenGL content.

So far I have experimented to integrate Panda3D with Qt in two ways:

- **run two event loops in parallel** - start the Panda3D engine in a child process and then using a pipe communicate with it
- **run a single event loop** - use the event loop of Panda3D engine to also handle the main event loop of Qt by adding a task to the engine's task manager to run `QApplication::processEvents()` on every cycle

In both cases I am handing over a window Id (`QWidget::winId()`) as the parent window of Panda3D.

---

**CASE 1 - parallel processes, separated event loops**

This resolution comes with a lot of overhead. All the communication between the Qt content (running in the parent process) needs to be sent (via pipe hence involving IPC) to the engine (running in the child process). This adds a lot of code complexity and in case of my logging (using Python's `logging` module with a custom logging handler that writes records into an SQLite3 database) introduces a whole lot of issues. Concurrent write access to a file between processes is a tricky thing in general and I'm definitely not an expert. This case however does not exhibit the behaviour I'm describing below. In this case however **the issue with OpenGL is not present!**

**CASE 2 - single process, single event loop**

In my opinion this is a more elegant and is what I would like to go with (if possible). An example can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/aleksandaratanasov/qtpanda3d/-/blob/pyside/pyside_panda3d_single_event_loop.py). I use the engine's main loop to process Qt's main loop. This is due to the fact that a 3D game engine usually would need to deal with far more events for a shorter period of time (processing rendering, audio, video, filesystem access, physics and so on) then a standard Qt GUI. This is also the recommended way as described in the [official documentation of the engine](https://docs.panda3d.org/1.10/python/programming/tasks-and-events/main-loop). The other way around (Qt's main loop handling Panda3D's) is also possible. Imho neither have anything to do with my issue namely the moment I add anything Qt-ish that uses OpenGL, the problem I've described above occurs. On Windows this is not a huge deal breaker since I can also use DirectX for the engine, while Qt does it's OpenGL thing. On Linux it is not possible (without something like `wine`). In addition I want to use exclusively OpenGL including GLSL.

---

Here is a visual representation of case 1 and case 2 (but with mixed DX9 and OpenGL):

[image: Separate processes or single process but mix between DX9 and OpenGL]

And below there are two visual representations of case 2 with only OpenGL:

[image: Black Panda3D window]

[image: Completely glitched QWebEngineView and black Panda3D window]

While Panda3D offers CPU rendering (aka `p3tinydisplay`), `QWebEngineView` does not. Falling back to CPU rendering on the engine side is not an option considering the huge amount of polygons I have to render not to mention the fact that I can do something more useful with the CPU (e.g. processing the physics).

Last but not least I have seen a [third integration attempt](https://discourse.panda3d.org/t/panda-in-pyqt/3964/2), which I quickly discarded - rendering the scene as an image to RAM, reading it in Qt, generating a `QPixmap` from it and painting on top of a `QLabel`. Needless to say this is a no go for my scenario due to the heavy hit on performance among others.

Any ideas how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think event loops have to do with anything here; the problem is that by default child windows get the same device-context (DC) as the parent. In your case that's a problem because two different components (Qt framework, and Panda3D engine) try to `ChoosePixelFormat` and initialize OpenGL context twice on the same DC, which is not supported.

The proper solution is to create the Panda3D engine `QWidget` from a `QWindow` with the `Qt::MSWindowsOwnDC` style, which corresponds to the [`CS_OWNDC` window-class style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-class-styles). Normally `QWidget` doesn't create any window at all -- but is rather implemented entirely within the Qt framework by drawing itself on the parent window.

Comment: Yes, the loop has probably nothing to do with the issue but rather that both are running in the same process and compete for the same OpenGL context. As for your solution I cannot take it because this will go against the sole reason why I went with this combination of technologies - multiplatform support. In fact I am creating this using set of features from another in-house software that is Windows-only - DX and WinAPI all the way.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: seems like you either find a multi-platform way to do that with Qt or a way to instruct Panda3D to use an existing context. For the former there's a `Qt::MSWindowsOwnDC` flag, and maybe you don't need anything special on other platforms (other than creating a native window with `QWindow`).

Comment: Well, yeah. I am looking into instructing Panda to use an existing context. :) As for `Qt::MSWindowsOwnDC` - while this may (haven't tried it) fix the issue on Windows, I don't see how this resolves the context conflict on any other platform.

Comment: @rbaleksandar: did you try creating a window (without `Qt::MSWindowsOwnDC`) on other platforms? There is a chance that on other platforms that is the default behavior. (There is an educated guess behind here, but it's beyond of what i'm willing to explain in a short comment.)

Comment: @rbaleksandar: also, instructing panda on using an existing context will cause problems if Qt and Panda expect contexts of different OpenGL versions or have conflicting expectations of the context state.